# android webrtc cannot stream voice

Tags: android, webrtc

I am building a voice chat app on android with webrtcI successfully established a connection with my emulator on my PC and streaming my voice in both directions. My phone was android 5.1 and my phone got bad and now am using version 4.4.2. When I try the app it connects well but cannot stream my voice here is what I get on my log:

```
D/OFFER: v=0
             o=- 757416304722047422 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
             s=-
             t=0 0
             a=group:BUNDLE audio
             a=msid-semantic: WMS LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID
             m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 127 126
             c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
             a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
             a=ice-ufrag:FkcTrOiVjoakQJoa
             a=ice-pwd:16SQFwIpnPEdmqyYC2PdSDzI
             a=fingerprint:sha-1 1F:85:D7:8C:DB:98:72:E7:D2:DE:52:A7:A4:B5:48:85:F1:BC:F3:AC
             a=setup:actpass
             a=mid:audio
             a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
             a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
             a=sendrecv
             a=rtcp-mux
             a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
             a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
             a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
             a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
             a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
             a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
             a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
             a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
             a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
             a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
             a=rtpmap:127 red/8000
             a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
             a=maxptime:60
             a=ssrc:954003986 cname:QR3nFlCQG7p7qQNo
             a=ssrc:954003986 msid:LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID AUDIO_TRACK_ID_LOCAL
             a=ssrc:954003986 mslabel:LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID
             a=ssrc:954003986 label:AUDIO_TRACK_ID_LOCAL
    D/AudioManager: SetCommunicationMode(1)@[tid=19672]
    D/HelpersAndroid: Attaching thread to JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioManager: setCommunicationMode(true)@[name=Thread-303, id=303]
    D/WebRtcAudioManager: changing audio mode to: MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
    D/HelpersAndroid: Detaching thread from JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/AudioTrackJni: InitPlayout@[tid=19672]
    D/HelpersAndroid: Attaching thread to JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: InitPlayout(sampleRate=44100, channels=1)
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: byteBuffer.capacity: 882
    D/AudioTrackJni: OnCacheDirectBufferAddress
    D/AudioTrackJni: direct buffer capacity: 882
    D/AudioTrackJni: frames_per_buffer: 441
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize: 4096
    D/AudioTrackJni: delay_in_milliseconds: 46
    D/HelpersAndroid: Detaching thread from JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/AudioTrackJni: StartPlayout@[tid=19672]
    D/HelpersAndroid: Attaching thread to JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: StartPlayout
    I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.media.AudioTrack.write, referenced from method org.webrtc.voiceengine.WebRtcAudioTrack$AudioTrackThread.run
    W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1101: Landroid/media/AudioTrack;.write (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;II)I
    D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0078
    D/HelpersAndroid: Detaching thread from JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrackThread@[name=AudioTrackJavaThread, id=307]
    D/ICE: IceCandidate added :candidate:547260449 1 udp 2122260223 10.0.2.15 36170 typ host generation 0
    D/ICE: IceCandidate added :candidate:1847424209 1 tcp 1518280447 10.0.2.15 60568 typ host tcptype passive generation 0
    D/AudioTrackJni: StopPlayout@[tid=19672]
    D/HelpersAndroid: Attaching thread to JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: StopPlayout
    D/HelpersAndroid: Detaching thread from JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/AudioManager: SetCommunicationMode(0)@[tid=19672]
    D/HelpersAndroid: Attaching thread to JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioManager: setCommunicationMode(false)@[name=Thread-319, id=319]
    D/WebRtcAudioManager: restoring audio mode to: MODE_NORMAL
    D/HelpersAndroid: Detaching thread from JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/AudioManager: SetCommunicationMode(1)@[tid=19672]
    D/HelpersAndroid: Attaching thread to JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioManager: setCommunicationMode(true)@[name=Thread-320, id=320]
    D/WebRtcAudioManager: changing audio mode to: MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
    D/HelpersAndroid: Detaching thread from JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/AudioTrackJni: InitPlayout@[tid=19672]
    D/HelpersAndroid: Attaching thread to JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: InitPlayout(sampleRate=44100, channels=1)
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: byteBuffer.capacity: 882
    D/AudioTrackJni: OnCacheDirectBufferAddress
    D/AudioTrackJni: direct buffer capacity: 882
    D/AudioTrackJni: frames_per_buffer: 441
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize: 4096
    D/AudioTrackJni: delay_in_milliseconds: 46
    D/HelpersAndroid: Detaching thread from JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/AudioTrackJni: StartPlayout@[tid=19672]
    D/HelpersAndroid: Attaching thread to JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: StartPlayout
    D/HelpersAndroid: Detaching thread from JVM@[tid=19672]
    D/WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrackThread@[name=AudioTrackJavaThread, id=324]
    D/OFFER: v=0
             o=- 2122221720328118009 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
             s=-
             t=0 0
             a=group:BUNDLE audio
             a=msid-semantic: WMS LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID
             m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 127 126
             c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
             a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
             a=ice-ufrag:FoasgPNFAm6dZWo8
             a=ice-pwd:lGnZzKSNLhH0vjt0sPw+NIaQ
             a=fingerprint:sha-1 45:15:D5:D0:6B:87:81:5D:61:A4:F8:AC:56:EB:E4:2F:1A:59:AA:16
             a=setup:actpass
             a=mid:audio
             a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
             a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
             a=sendrecv
             a=rtcp-mux
             a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
             a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
             a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
             a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
             a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
             a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
             a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
             a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
             a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
             a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
             a=rtpmap:127 red/8000
             a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
             a=maxptime:60
             a=ssrc:3345216954 cname:chD7I2bAd/Iwdbk1
             a=ssrc:3345216954 msid:LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID AUDIO_TRACK_ID_LOCAL
             a=ssrc:3345216954 mslabel:LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID
             a=ssrc:3345216954 label:AUDIO_TRACK_ID_LOCAL
    D/ICE: IceCandidate added :candidate:547260449 1 udp 2122260223 10.0.2.15 41078 typ host generation 1
    D/ICE: IceCandidate added :candidate:1847424209 1 tcp 1518280447 10.0.2.15 33099 typ host tcptype passive generation 1.
```

I read in some forums that this is happens because android.media.AudioTrack.write is absent in versions of android prior to 5.0 i am using io.pristine:libjingle:9127@aar what can I do to solve this problem?

Here is my source code :

```
package com.example.nyari.webopeer;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.webrtc.AudioSource;
    import org.webrtc.AudioTrack;
    import org.webrtc.DataChannel;
    import org.webrtc.IceCandidate;
    import org.webrtc.MediaConstraints;
    import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
    import org.webrtc.PeerConnection;
    import org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory;
    import org.webrtc.SdpObserver;
    import org.webrtc.SessionDescription;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import io.socket.client.Socket;
    import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PeerConnection.Observer,SdpObserver {

        static {
            System.loadLibrary("louts");
        }

        public native Socket socketIO();

        EditText edit;
        TextView hello;
        Button button, button2, button3;
        ListView listView;
        ArrayList<String> list;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        Socket client;
        Thread t, voice, play_v;
        Emitter.Listener Hello, enterGroup, leaveGroup, message, androidi, connect, candidate, offer, answer;
        String MESSAGE;
        List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServer;
        String Type_Signal;
        /////SOUND MANAGEMENT
        private static String AUDIO_TRACK_ID_LOCAL = "AUDIO_TRACK_ID_LOCAL";
        private static String AUDIO_TRACK_ID_REMOTE = "AUDIO_TRACK_ID_REMOTE";
        private static String LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID = "LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID";
        PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory;
        AudioTrack localAudioTrack, remoteAudioTrack;
        PeerConnection peerConnection;
        MediaConstraints audioConstraints;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //INITIALISE Peerconnection factory and verifying if it is initialised if not donot continue
            boolean peer = PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    true,//boolean for initializing audio portion of webrtc
                    false,//boolean for initializing video portiong of webrtc
                    true,//boolean for hardware acceleration
                    null//renderEGLContext Can be provided to support HW video decoding to texture and will be used to create a shared EGL context on video decoding thread
            );
            if (peer = true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Webrtc initialised", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ///IF peerconnectionfactory is correctly initialed now create a peerconnectionfactory object
                peerConnectionFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory();
                Log.i("PCTEST", " factory value " + String.valueOf(peerConnectionFactory));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Webrtc did not initialised", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //SET mediaconstaints
            audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
            audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));
            audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "false"));
            audioConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
            //// First we create an AudioSource
            AudioSource audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
            // Once we have that, we can create our AudioTrack
    // Note that AUDIO_TRACK_ID can be any string that uniquely
    // identifies that audio track in your application
            localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack(AUDIO_TRACK_ID_LOCAL, audioSource);
            // We start out with an empty MediaStream object,
    // created with help from our PeerConnectionFactory
    // Note that LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID can be any string
            MediaStream mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream(LOCAL_MEDIA_STREAM_ID);
            mediaStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);

            /////////////
            //////////////////////
            //BELOW E DEAL WITH SIGNALING AND SOCKET.IO
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            hello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            ///////////////
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, list);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ////////////////////////
            edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
            ///////////////////////
            emit();
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
            //////////////////////
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
            /////////////////////
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
    ////INIT WEBRTC PEERCONNECTION
            iceServer = new ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer>();
            iceServer.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("", "", ""));
            peerConnection = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(iceServer, audioConstraints, this);
            peerConnection.addStream(mediaStream);
            t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    client = socketIO();
                    client.on("Hello", Hello);
                    client.on("connect", connect);
                    client.on("candidate", candidate);
                    client.on("offer", offer);
                    client.on("answer", answer);
                    client.on("android", androidi);
           /* client.on("leaveGroup",leaveGroup);
            client.on("message",message);*/
                    client.connect();
                }
            });
            t.start();


        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            client.disconnect();
            t.interrupt();
        }

        private void emit() {
            Hello = new Emitter.Listener() {///HELLO MESSAGE WITH SERVER
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) args[0];
                            try {
                                MESSAGE = obj.getString("ki");
                               hello.setText(MESSAGE);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            };
            //////////
            connect = new Emitter.Listener() {///RECEIVE VOICE DATA FROM SERVER
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    JSONObject reg = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        reg.put("grp", "form_1");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    client.emit("enterGroup", reg);
                }
            };
            ///////
            //////////
            candidate = new Emitter.Listener() {///RECEIVE VOICE DATA FROM SERVER
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    JSONObject reg = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        reg.put("grp", "form_1");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };
            //////////
            offer = new Emitter.Listener() {///RECEIVE VOICE DATA FROM SERVER
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    Type_Signal="answer";
                   /* peerConnection.createAnswer(MainActivity.this,audioConstraints);*/
                  //  SessionDescription fi=(SessionDescription)args[0];
                    final SessionDescription sesso=new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.OFFER,args[0].toString());

                    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(MainActivity.this,sesso);
                    peerConnection.createAnswer(MainActivity.this,audioConstraints);
                    /*
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sesso.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });*/
                    Log.d("OFFER", sesso.description);

                }
            };

            //////////
            answer = new Emitter.Listener() {///RECEIVE VOICE DATA FROM SERVER
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    final SessionDescription sesso=new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER,args[0].toString());
                    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(MainActivity.this,sesso);
                 /*   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sesso.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });*/
                    Log.d("ANSWER",sesso.toString());
                }
            };
            //////////
            androidi = new Emitter.Listener() {///RECEIVE VOICE DATA FROM SERVER
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    ///////////////USED WHEN OFFER IS CREATED TO EMIT OFFER
            /*       Type_Signal="offer";
                    peerConnection.createOffer(MainActivity.this, audioConstraints);*/
                }
            };
        }


        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();


        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();


        }

        @Override
        public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
    peerConnection.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
            Log.d("ICE","IceCandidate added :"+iceCandidate.sdp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            if(mediaStream.audioTracks.size()>0){
                remoteAudioTrack=mediaStream.audioTracks.get(0);
            }
            Log.d("STREAMA","Receiving streams");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            remoteAudioTrack=mediaStream.audioTracks.remove();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
          //  hello.setText(sessionDescription.description);
            peerConnection.setLocalDescription(MainActivity.this,sessionDescription);
        /*    JSONObject regu = new JSONObject();
            try {
                regu.put(Type_Signal, sessionDescription);
                client.emit(Type_Signal,regu);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            client.emit(Type_Signal,sessionDescription.description);
           // Log.d("ANSWERING",sessionDescription.description);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetSuccess() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateFailure(final String s) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to create offer because " + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onSetFailure(final String s) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to set offer because " + s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a recent version of libjingle this one 'io.pristine:libjingle:9944@aar' hope it helps someone